# Oral exercise from an entrance examination: polynomials and vector spaces

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $k$ be an infinite field and $E$ a $k$-vector space of finite dimension.

1. Let $f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^d P_i(t)v_i$ ($f:k\to E$) where $P_i$ are polynomials of $k[x]$ and $v_i$ are vectors. Let $F$ be a vector subspace of $E$. Show that one of the following propositions holds:

   - $\forall t\in k$, $f(t)\in F$ or
   - there is a finite subset $X$ of $k$ such that $\forall t\in k\setminus X$, $f(t)\not\in F$.
2. Let $F_1,\dots,F_n$ be strict vector subspaces of E. Show, using question 1, that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i\neq E$.

---

I've been stuck on this exercise for some time, I tried to consider the case where $F$ was of codimension 1 without success. I also tried to decompose the $v_i$ as the sum of an element of $F$ and one of its complement in $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F'$ be a complement of $F $, so that $E $ is the direct sum of  $F $ and $F'$. Write $v_j=w_j+z_j $, with $w_j\in F $ and $z_j\in F'$. Then $$f (t)=\sum_jP_j (t)w_j+\sum_jP_j (t)z_j. $$ By removing elements (and changing the polynomials accordingly) if necessary, we may assume that $z_1,\ldots, z_d $ are linearly independent.

Now let  $Y=\{t:\ f (t)\in F\} $. Then $$Y=\{t:\ P_1 (t)=\cdots=P_d (t)=0\}. $$ So either $Y=k $ (when $P_1=\cdots=P_d=0$),  or $Y $ is finite (as a nonzero polynomial has finitely many roots). This gives the two cases.

Comment: This is a perfect answer to the first question! Thank you so much

Comment: If they are not linearly independent,  then one is a linear combination of the others. Say $z_3=az_1+bz_2$. Then  $$P_1z_1+P_2z_2+P_3z_3=(P_1+aP_3)z_1+(P_2+bP_3)z_2. $$ Repeat until only linearly independent vectors remain.